# Error writing dataframe to avro in spark: NoSuchElementException

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to save a dataframe to an avro file in spark but if fails with just one dataframe. The code seems right because it works perfect with other dataframes and even with a subset of the same dataframe:

```
def write_df_avro(df, outputFolder, outputFile):
    outputFile = os.path.join(outputFolder, outputFile)
    df_coal = df
    df_coal.registerTempTable('table')
    df_coal.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").mode('overwrite').save(outputFile)
```

I'm getting error writing rows because of *java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator*

Any idea?

This is the stack output:

```
  WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 48.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 605, 192.168.0.1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:250)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
          at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
          at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
          at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
          at scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$Elements.next(IndexedSeqLike.scala:64)
          at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroOutputWriter$$anonfun$com$databricks$spark$avro$AvroOutputWriter$$createConverterToAvro$7.apply(AvroOutputWriter.scala:141)
          at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroOutputWriter.write(AvroOutputWriter.scala:70)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.OutputWriter.writeInternal(interfaces.scala:380)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:242)
          ... 8 more

  16/10/13 18:08:29 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 48 in stage 18.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
  16/10/13 18:08:29 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job.
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 48 in stage 18.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 48.3 in stage 18.0 (TID 671, 192.168.0.3): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:250)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
          at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
          at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
          at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
          at scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$Elements.next(IndexedSeqLike.scala:64)
          at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroOutputWriter$$anonfun$com$databricks$spark$avro$AvroOutputWriter$$createConverterToAvro$7.apply(AvroOutputWriter.scala:141)
          at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroOutputWriter.write(AvroOutputWriter.scala:70)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.OutputWriter.writeInternal(interfaces.scala:380)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:242)
          ... 8 more

  Driver stacktrace:
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1294)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1282)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1281)
          at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
          at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1281)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
          at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1507)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1469)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
          at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
          at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)
          at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)
          at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1914)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:69)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
          at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:933)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:933)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:197)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:146)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:137)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
          at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
          at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
          at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
          at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
          at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
          at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:250)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
          at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
          ... 1 more
  Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
          at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
          at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
          at scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$Elements.next(IndexedSeqLike.scala:64)
          at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroOutputWriter$$anonfun$com$databricks$spark$avro$AvroOutputWriter$$createConverterToAvro$7.apply(AvroOutputWriter.scala:141)
          at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroOutputWriter.write(AvroOutputWriter.scala:70)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.OutputWriter.writeInternal(interfaces.scala:380)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:242)
          ... 8 more
  16/10/13 18:08:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 100.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 657, 192.168.0.3): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
  16/10/13 18:08:29 ERROR DefaultWriterContainer: Job job_201610131808_0000 aborted.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/xxx/xxx/avro_to_df.py", line 194, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/xxx/xxx/avro_to_df.py", line 172, in main
      write_df_avro(new_df, tempfile.gettempdir() , 'sacame_de_aquiiii' )
    File "/home/xxx/xxx/avro_to_df.py", line 92, in write_df_avro
      df_coal.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").mode('overwrite').save(outputFile)
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 332, in save
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 36, in deco
      w.close()
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
  py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o264.save.
  : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:156)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:69)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
          at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:933)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:933)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:197)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:146)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:137)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
          at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
          at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
          at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
          at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
          at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
          at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 48 in stage 18.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 48.3 in stage 18.0 (TID 671, 192.168.0.3): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:250)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
          at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
          at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
          at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
          at scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$Elements.next(IndexedSeqLike.scala:64)
          at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroOutputWriter$$anonfun$com$databricks$spark$avro$AvroOutputWriter$$createConverterToAvro$7.apply(AvroOutputWriter.scala:141)
          at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroOutputWriter.write(AvroOutputWriter.scala:70)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.OutputWriter.writeInternal(interfaces.scala:380)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:242)
          ... 8 more

  Driver stacktrace:
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1294)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1282)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1281)
          at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
          at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1281)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
          at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1507)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1469)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
          at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
          at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)
          at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)
          at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1914)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
          ... 27 more
  Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:250)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
          at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
          at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
          ... 1 more
  Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
          at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
          at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
          at scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$Elements.next(IndexedSeqLike.scala:64)
          at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroOutputWriter$$anonfun$com$databricks$spark$avro$AvroOutputWriter$$createConverterToAvro$7.apply(AvroOutputWriter.scala:141)
          at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroOutputWriter.write(AvroOutputWriter.scala:70)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.OutputWriter.writeInternal(interfaces.scala:380)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:242)
          ... 8 more
```

Comment: Can you post a copy of the schema you are trying to save (use "df.printSchema()" ).  The error happens when converting your DF data types to the avro internal types that will be written out.

Comment: Thank you @RyanW for your help. The schema was simple, just doubles and strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The data was wrong and there were rows with less columns than the whole dataset.